# [FLUTTER]: Cut text depending of height of ListTile

Tags: string, flutter, dart, text

I have the following widget. The problem is I need to cut my **subtitle string** depending on the height and width of the `ListTile`. Now, height of the `ListTile` depends on length of substring I have. Longer is my substring, longer is the height of the `ListTile`. It looks awkward. Putting `ListTile` inside `Container` widget is good, but the substring overlaps the next `ListTile` content. it looks terrible too. Another solution was using `FittedBox`, I thought. But, I need the fixed size of each `ListTile`, without changing the **fontSize**. That's why the `FixedBox` doesn't fit me:) It changes the fontSize. I need to cut my string when it reaches the end of the `ListTile`. How can I solve this?

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => ProductScreen(product),
      ),
    );
  },
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 8.0,
          horizontal: 4.0,
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            product.title.toUpperCase(),
            style: Styles.listTitleStyle,
          ),
          subtitle: Text(
            product.description,
            style: Styles.listBodyStyle,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const Divider(height: 1.0),
    ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your text widget add something like this,

```
subtitle: Text(
    maxLines: 2,   //customize your number of lines
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,    //add this to set (...) at the end of sentence 
    product.description,
    style: Styles.listBodyStyle,
),
```